# PostgreSQL select distinct by two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, distinct

I have a table

| senderId | receiverId | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | "2022-08-10T07:21:12.881Z" |
| 2 | 1 | "2022-08-10T07:28:12.881Z" |
| 2 | 1 | "2022-08-10T07:22:12.881Z" |
| 1 | 2 | "2022-08-10T07:25:12.881Z" |

Current query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("senderId", "receiverId") "sender"."id" AS "senderId", "receiver"."id" AS "receiverId", cm."createdAt" AS "createdAt" FROM "chat_message" "cm" LEFT JOIN "user" "sender" ON "sender"."id"="cm"."senderId"  LEFT JOIN "user" "receiver" ON "receiver"."id"="cm"."receiverId" WHERE "senderId" = 2 OR "receiverId" = 2 ORDER BY "senderId", "receiverId" ASC, cm."createdAt" DESC
```

Current result

| senderId | receiverId | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | "2022-08-10T07:25:12.881Z" |
| 2 | 1 | "2022-08-10T07:28:12.881Z" |

Expected result

| senderId | receiverId | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | "2022-08-10T07:28:12.881Z" |

So, I need to select only one row in this pair where the date is bigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `LEAST`/`GREATEST` trick here along with `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (LEAST(senderId, receiverId),
                    GREATEST(senderId, receiverId))
       LEAST(senderId, receiverId) AS senderId,
       GREATEST(senderId, receiverId) AS receiverId,
       createdAt
FROM chat_message
ORDER BY 1, 2, createdAt DESC;
```